# Qt Creator 6.0.1 and lagging autocompletion

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt6

Im using new Qt Creator version 6.0.1, but its autocompletion lags a lot. I set  auto-completion timeout in ms to 0, but it didnt help. Any idea whats causing it? Some plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It was ClangCodeModel plugin that was causing the lag :/